# Unexpected Identifier when parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm getting a JSON object back from php contains just a count of distinct values for a column. Here's the relevant part:

```
[Object]
0: Object
count(distinct value): "456"
```

"Value" is the name of the column (and, yes, I know it's not a good choice for a column name).

My jquery looks like this. I'm trying to just get the "456" and append it to a div.

```
$.getJSON('attribute_count.php', function(data) {
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
var attribute_count = val.count(distinct value);
$('#attribute_count').append(attribute_count);
});
});
```

However, this throws an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on the line:

```
var attribute_count = val.count(distinct value);
```

I've used this exact syntax to get and append other data from this database with no problem. I'm guessing the "count(distinct value)" part is the problem, but not sure how to correct it. Here's the relevant part from my PHP:

```
$sql = "select count(distinct value) from full_data_complete;";
$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: `distinct value` is simply not JavaScript syntax. That makes sense in SQL.

Comment: as Pointy has pointed out `val.count(distinct value)` is not correct syntax... ignoring this is `$result` valid JSON? Your error refers to the response not being valid.

Comment: `console.log(data)` would show you exactly what keys you have to work with.

Comment: @MarcB I did that and what you see in my question is what I get back. I used `count(distinct value)` as the key and it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is looking for a `count` method on `val`, along with some undefined parameters.

The best solution would be to alias your column in SQL, using the `AS` keyword.

Your SQL would then look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct value) AS distinct_value_count FROM full_data_complete;
```

You can now access it in your javascript as:

```
data.distinct_value_count
```

You don't need to loop the data, as it is an object.

```
$.getJSON('attribute_count.php', function(data) {
    var attribute_count = data.distinct_value_count;
    $('#attribute_count').append(attribute_count);
});
```

Comment: This worked great and is probably what I should have done in the first place, but wasn't sure how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if `val` is in fact the object containing a `count(distinct value)` field, you'll want to say:

```
var attribute_count = val["count(distinct value)"];
```

Comment: This came back with attribute_count as undefined. Perhaps I shouldn't be using val, but I'm not totally clear what to use instead.